# How to handle Tribools

Tags: c

In C true is anything that isn't 0. (But quite often we use enums to define values for the states). So to do tests for truth we can do the following:

```
typedef enum
{
    FALSE,
    TRUE
} BOOL;

// Some function
BOOL n = isTrue();

if (n)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Which there is some debate, but myself and others prefer to:

```
if (n == TRUE)
{
    // Do something
}
```

But if for some reason the `isTrue()` function returned a value other than 1 for true then the latter doesn't work and true is seen as false.

I have been going through a code review marking that the first way should be the way to do it. However I have suddenly realised that sometimes we need the idea of a 3rd state when a value hasn't been set. But is it even possible to do this in C and still do our boolean comparisons in the first way as it seems if we assign any other value to be this "NULL" value then it will still record as true

Comment: IMHO the first variant is **not** preferred to the second. The second is more readable, unless you have proper variable names, like `isBlue` etc.

Comment: @Matthias, it is certainly preferred to the second, if it just be for the reason that `TRUE` is nothing that is defined in the standard, the value to use are `true` or `1`. But for `bool` the first is really preferable. Were one can discuss this is for other types, such as pointers, but not for `bool`.

Comment: I wasn't sure if booleans existed as a type in the C standards now. Most places I have used C tends to have an enum defined for TRUE and FALSE which perhaps I should have made more clear above

Comment: @JensGustedt: The OP did not mention bool at all, and `bool` is not a C type (`_Bool` is). Also `true` and `false` are only macros, and usually you have macros or an enum for `TRUE` and `FALSE` as well. If your variable **is** an boolean **and** you can see it from name, then I agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  You will need an explicit comparison.  I would suggest using an `enum` type for clarity:

```
typedef enum {
    FALSE = 0,
    TRUE = 1,
    FILENOTFOUND = 2
} truth;
```

This leads to fairly clean code constructs:

```
truth n;

// ...

switch (n) {
case FALSE:          // Blah
case TRUE:           // Blah
case FILENOTFOUND:   // Blah
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I suppose that where types are able to have this 3rd state that having them as a specific type (Such as a typedef of TRIBOOL) then highlights that you have to compare against TRUE, FALSE or FILENOTFOUND (as in your example). I also considered you coould have a struct with a "null" flag is another option but I was curious as to seeing if there is a recommendation in the wider C world

Comment: @Firedragon: Yes, exactly.  In my example, the typedef is called `truth`.

Comment: Because I'm not sure Firedragon will get the reference: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_.aspx

Comment: @RogerLipscombe I have seen that before but it had slipped my mind. So thanks for that.

Comment: This is closely related to the `ZomBoolean` class, which is identical to `truth` except `FILENOTFOUND` has the value `53` (instead of `2`) and it has the additional value, `ZOMBIE` which is `-1`.

Comment: A better name for the type might be `knowledge`, although there's a danger of getting into deep philosophical waters ;-)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Would the problem with an enum like this though be that all enums would then, kind of, have a potential third state? As enums can't be hidden in C as with namespaces or classes in C++ can they? I suppose where you know a boolean is either true or false you would just then ignore that it exists and just test in the same way as my first example? Moving from C++ back to C is taking me some time! :-)

Comment: @Firedragon: I'm not sure I understand.  My thought is that if you need a standard 2-state variable, then always use a `bool`.  If you need a 3-state variable, then always use a `truth`/`TRIBOOL`.  So long as you're consistent, then everything should be ok.  The only problem is that the individual enum names (`FALSE`, `TRUE`, etc.) might clash with existing names, so you may want to rename them as `TRIBOOL_FALSE`, `TRIBOOL_TRUE`, etc.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth It was the name clashing that I meant but your answer covers that. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to opt for an `int`. You could use -ve numbers for false, +ve for true and zero for "don't know".

You'd still need to be careful not to use it as `if (thing)`, but you have that problem with the others as well.

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote, anything that is not 0 evaluates to 'true'. That means C is literally *incapable* of identifying a third state under the circumstances you described: C only distinguishes between 'false' (which is 0) and 'not-false' (i. e. 'true', which is anything that isn't 0).

A slightly hackish alternative to the enum-based solution would be doing tests like

```
#DEFINE NOTSET -1


if (a == NOTSET) {
    /* Stuff that happens when a is not set*/ 
}

else if (a) {
    /* Stuff that happens when a is true*/
}

else {
    /*Stuff that happens when a is false*/
}
```

but I frankly wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Indeed, this is not recommended, because accidentally switching the order of the comparisons will lead to broken code.

Comment: You still see it occasionally - that's why I thought I'd mention it - but it's a Bad Idea, I agree.

Comment: I agree it looks like a hackish way to do it but it is useful to show that it "could" be done this way. Sometimes showing a way to do it and saying why you shouldn't is good for learning I think in case it is ever seen in code one needs to work with.